# Como ordenar alfabeticamente grocery crud

Tags: php, mysql, grocery-crud

como puedo ordenar de forma alfabética un campo llamando nombre de forma alfabética, el problema radica en que los datos están guardados unos en mayúsculas otros en minúsculas y otros en mayúsculas y minúsculas, y cuando llamo a la tabla con `grocery crud`, pues resulta que no me lo ordena por dicho problema.

```
$crud->order_by('nombre','asc');
```

Esta seria la forma natural de ordenar, pero no me funciona. por mis tipos de datos.

Comment: Ya he podido resolverlo a medias, resulta que los datos no los estaba guardando de la forma adecuada en la db, los guardaba con espacios etc, eso me causaba el conflicto en el order, pero ahora lo que requiero hacer, es que antes de guardarlo quitarles los espacios, para que funcione bien. pero hacerlo mediante grocery crup